# Verb fahren uses

Tags: verb, meaning-in-context, conjugation

> Es fahren viele Leute mit dem Bus.

Here in this example, why is verb *fahren* not conjugated? It should be *Es fährt viele Leute mit dem Bus*.

Please guide me, why verb here in infinitive form and not in conjugated form.

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to German SE. Just a hint: it might look like an infinitive, but it isn't. Please consult a conjugation table. And please take the [tour](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 5):

Your example is a special construction where "es" is a placeholder for the subject. The actual subject of the sentence is "viele Leute", which is plural and requires plural conjugation of "fahren". The verb actually is conjugated here.

This special construction is used for stylistic reasons and emphasis. In German, we use different word order for emphasis. But the verb must be at the second position (in a main clause). Thus, we use "es" as a placeholder to be able to change the order of subject and verb.

Without it, the sentence would be "Viele Leute fahren mit dem Bus."

Answer (score 2):

Don't let word order fool you. *Es* isn't the subject. It's an expletive. The subject is *viele Leute* and as that's plural, *fahren* is conjugated in third person plural.

You can use the expletive *es* in first position if the subject is third person singular or plural, and if you don't want to put the subject or anything else in front. That is for stylistic reasons. Such a main clause with *es* in front has no topic. All other declarative main clauses in German are topicalized.

> Viele Leute fahren mit dem Bus.

The subject *viele Leute* is the topic.

> Mit dem Bus fahren viele Leute.

The adverbial *mit dem Bus* is the topic.

> Es fahren viele Leute mit dem Bus.

There is no topic.